# Conditional Loop to Filter Cell Content Values

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements, filtering, cell

I am basically having the problem of deleting certain values and keeping others in a cell of cells.

I create a cell called distances and then want to filter out the values based on the two criteria "blockade and blockadeouter". I am unable to do so with the initial cells in the distance cell remaining empty but more importantly the filtering is not working in the sense I see values outside the  specified range staying in distance cell.

I want to store the coordinates xinit,yinit,zinit for the distances which satisfy by range property and store these coordinates in the posx,posy,posz.

Not sure of the mistake I am making. All and any help is welcome.

Thanks

```
kb = 1.38065*10^(-23) ; %Boltzmann Constant
amu = 1.660539040*10^-27; % atomic mass unit
mRb= 85;%mass of Rubidium 85
c = 299792458; % speed of light
e=1.6021892*10^-19;%electron unit charge
epsilon0 = 8.854 * 10^-12;

%=============Minimum Allowable Distance/Blockade Radius=====================
a = 12.8*10^-6;
blockade =14*10^-6;%lower limit for filtering
blockadeouter = blockade + a;%upper limit for filtering

sigmax = 40;
sigmay = 40;
sigmaz = 0;
%==================Number of Scan Steps====================================
npics =50; %number of iterations
%=============Number of initial particles in the excitation volume in the MOT Stage===================
numberofparticles =100;
%=============Creating a cell system for importing GPT Data into===========
distances = cell(npics,1);%Collecting all distances between particles
posx = cell(npics,1);
posy = cell(npics,1);
posz = cell(npics,1);

for n = 1 : 1 : npics
    fprintf('%d ',n);
    %Declaration of orgin for simulation
    mux = 0; muy = 0; muz =0;
    %Creating a x,y,z coordinate system for the ion
    xinit = normrnd(mux,sigmax*10^-6,[1 numberofparticles]);
    yinit = normrnd(muy,sigmay*10^-6,[1 numberofparticles]);
    zinit = normrnd(muz,sigmaz*10^-6,[1 numberofparticles]);

    for ii =  1 : 1 : numberofparticles

        for jj = ii+1 : 1 : numberofparticles

            distances{ii}{jj} = sqrt((xinit(ii) - xinit(jj)).^2 + (yinit(ii) - yinit(jj)).^2 + (zinit(ii) - zinit(jj)).^2);

            if (distances{ii}{jj} >= blockade) && (distances{ii}{jj} <= blockadeouter)
                posx{n}{jj} = xinit(jj);
                posy{n}{jj} = yinit(jj);
                posz{n}{jj} = 0;
            end

        end
    end
end % end of npics loop

figure
for ii = 1:1:length(distances)
    trial{ii} = cell2mat(distances{ii,1}(1,:));
end
trial = cell2mat(trial);
grid on;
title('Filtered Distances')
hist(trial)
```

Comment: Rather than struggling with cell-arrays of cell-arrays, why not use regular 2-d numeric arrays and use NaN to signify missing data (where you were using empty [] arrays before)? E.g. initialise something like this `distances = NaN(npics,numberofparticles);` and then use `distances(ii,jj) = ...`, and similar for `posx`, `posy` and `posz`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what was the problem with the conditional statement but i was able to solve the problem by doing the following:

```
for ii =  1 : 1 : numberofparticles

        for jj = ii+1 : 1 : numberofparticles

            distances{ii}{jj} = sqrt((xinit(ii) - xinit(jj)).^2 + (yinit(ii) - yinit(jj)).^2 + (zinit(ii) - zinit(jj)).^2);
            if distances{ii}{jj} > blockadeouter
                distances{ii}{jj} = [];
            end

            if distances{ii}{jj} < blockade
                distances{ii}{jj} = [];
            else
                posx{n}{jj} = xinit(jj);
                posy{n}{jj} = yinit(jj);
                posz{n}{jj} = zinit(jj);
            end

        end
    end
```